# gitlab repository URL unchanged after reverse proxy changes

Tags: nginx, gitlab, reverse-proxy

I am using a nginx reverse proxy to serve gitlab web app on port 80. ie nginx reverse proxy will redirect queries to http://ip-address/gitlab to http://ip-address:8000/gitlab . I have updated 'external_url' in my 'gitlab.rb' file. Everything is working (ie I am able to access the gitlab web-intrface via http://ip-address/gitlab ), except the generated git clone URLs. When I create new git projects, the repo URL is shown as http://ip-addeess:8000/gitlab/user/testproject.git. ie the port is still there. How can I remove the port?

Comment: What is your gitlab config?

Answer (score 0):

The displayed repository URL is generated from the parameter `external_url` in your `gitlab.rb` file.

You should set it like this:

```
external_url 'http://ip-address/gitlab'
```

Then run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` to apply this change.

Comment: i have already done that. So I am already able to access the gitlab UI via 'http://ip-address/gitlab'. But still when  I create a new project, the git URL is having the port, ie "http://ip-addeess:8000/gitlab/user/testproject.git". So the problem is only in GIT urls.

Comment: Is it a gitlab-omnibus install ? Or a manual install ? Changing this settings + `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Add "proxy_set_header Host $http_host;" in your "location / { directive.
Then restart nginx.
It should resolve your issue